# fixing linux mplayer library problem

Tags: linux, mplayer

While trying to use mplayer or mencoder i get a library error on **libsmbclient.so.0** the file seems to be available if you check below but somehow its not pointed to the right place. This is centos5. Does anyone know what i can do to point **libsmbclient.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsmbclient.so.0** i am guessing that will fix my issue.

root@server1 [/usr/bin]# mplayer
mplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libsmbclient.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@server1 [/usr/bin]# mencoder
mencoder: error while loading shared libraries: libsmbclient.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

root@server1 [/usr/bin]# which mplayer
/usr/local/bin/mplayer
root@server1 [/usr/bin]# which mencoder
/usr/local/bin/mencoder

root@server1 [/usr/bin]# locate libsmbclient
/usr/lib64/libsmbclient.so.0

root@server1 [/usr/bin]# ldd /usr/local/bin/mplayer
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libfaac.so.0 => /usr/local/MediaLibs/lib/libfaac.so.0 (0xf7f20000)
        libx264.so.59 => /usr/local/MediaLibs/lib/libx264.so.59 (0xf7e67000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00514000)
        libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/local/MediaLibs/lib/libmp3lame.so.0 (0xf7dec000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x005f9000)
        **libsmbclient.so.0 => not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mplayer and mencoder want the 32-bit `libsmbclient.so.0`, not the 64-bit one. You need to install the 32-bit version of `libsmbclient.so`.

Comment: ok... and how do i go and fix this?

Comment: @Joan - what distribution are you using?

Comment: @Joan - I don't have access to a CentOS 5 box right now, but I think you can install it with: `yum install libsmbclient.i386`